# Compile-Time detection of >= Alexandria 11.3

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

How do you (compile-time) detect the difference between Alexandria 11.2 and 11.3 (or, rather, how do you detect you are at 11.3 or later?)

Both have CompilerVersion and RTLVersion value at 35.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are constants `RTLVersion111`, `RTLVersion112` and `RTLVersion113` declared depending on the version you are compiling with. These can be detected like this:

```
{$IF declared(RTLVersion113)}
  ...
{$IFEND}
```

Comment: Thank you - I have added a more elaborate answer based on your info, but you still get the points for leading me there :-). Alexandria3 should be defined using my extended answer if you are at least on v11.3

Answer (score 0):

Extended Answer, based on Uwe Raabe's answer:

```
{$IF CompilerVersion > 35 }
  {$DEFINE Alexandria3 }
{$ELSEIF CompilerVersion < 35 }
  {$UNDEF Alexandria3 }
{$ELSEIF Declared(RTLVersion113) }
  {$DEFINE Alexandria3 }
{$ELSE }
  {$UNDEF Alexandria3 }
{$ENDIF }
```

Now you can

```
{$IFDEF Alexandria3 }
```

to conditionally compile code for Alexandria3 or later.

Comment: Likely because it is more of a "what I did with the answer" comment than an answer to the  question. (I did not downvote).

Comment: I would use a single `{$IF}` like this: `{$IF (CompilerVersion > 35) OR ((CompilerVersion = 35) AND Declared(RTLVersion113)) } {$DEFINE Alexandria3} {$ELSE} {$UNDEF Alexandria3} {$IFEND}`

Comment: @brian Actually, it answers the question precisely (which the accepted answer does not): "how do you detect 11.3 OR LATER?"... (and who deleted my initial question?)